# Drag and drop issue, currently using jquery sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I apologize that I have a very surface level understanding on Jquery and I just cant seem to find the right keywords to google the answer, or perhaps there just isnt.

Basically my developers are working on this website which uses Jquery sortable. I have products which I draw from a database on the left and placeholders on the right. the workflow can be seen in the picture [workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KesCj.jpg). I have products which I can drag and drop to the basket. For the products, I can scroll through the pages and drag and drop anytime. However, I now need to create another "basket". Which requires me to switch between the basket anytime, possibly with a "next" and "prev" button. My developers was explaining to me that they are unable to do it because,

1. the position of the items in my basket is important, i.e. first box will always be item 1, second box will always be item 2, and so on. (items will be displayed later according to the numbered boxes )
2. they need to refresh the page in order to switch basket due to point (1).
3. refreshing the page might cause the values for the products to reset, i.e. if I scrolled through the pages and I switch basket, I will end up back at product page 1, which means i have to scroll through the pages again.

May I know if that is the limitations of jquery sortable? or is there something that they will be able to do in order to create another "basket" and able to scroll the "basket" without refreshing the page? Is there anything else which I can use for this issue?

EDIT: here is the script!

```
    <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
                    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                    update: function (event, ui) {

                        var licont = $("#sortable2 .ProItem").length;

                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {

                        if (event.target.id == 'sortable1' && ui.item[0].title != "") {
                            $(".proli:last").remove();
                        }
                        //console.log(ui.item.index());
                        $("#sortable2 li").each(function(i,o){
                            $(this).find('h4').html(i+1);
                        })
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
            });
        </script>
```

your help is greatly appreciated!! thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on your description, without being able to see any code, this sounds like an issue with how the have coded the site and not a limitation. If you can use pastebin or jsfiddle.net to create an example of the code, we could help further. Otherwise, it's all speculation.

Comment: I have added the script!

Comment: This is more helpful in understanding the usage. It's hard to tell the flow here from this. Could you provide some example of the HTML that this presented or worked with?